# How to view the source code for map/reduce in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have written 2 functions for mapping and one for reducing in MongoDB. When I run this command below, it returns only the results for the MapReduce Code. I would like to see the source code to make some changes.

db.mapreduce_result.find().pretty()

Thanks,

Comment: You mention _writing 2 functions for mapping and one for reducing in MongoDB_, can you show the code for this too? The `mapreduce_result` collection is usually the output from a map reduce operation on a collection of the form `db.collection.mapReduce(
                     mapFunction,
                     reduceFunction,
                     { out: "mapreduce_result" }
                   )`

Answer (score 0):

One can use [toSource()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource) to find the source code of any Javascript method.

> The toSource() method returns a string representing the source code of the object.

Since mongo shell is a complete JS interpreter you can use this method.

In your case the command would be: `db.mapreduce_result.find().pretty().toSource()`.

Example: You can see the result when I used it for `db.collection.find()` method:

[image: Example of running toSource() in my mongo shell]